# i cannot place a relative layout below a sibling listView?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have this xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="blocked"
            android:id="@+id/isBlocked_cb"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/phone_editText"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/phone_editText"
            android:layout_above="@+id/comments_list"
            android:checked="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>


    <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/phone_editText"
            android:hint="enter phone"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="search"
            android:id="@+id/search_btn"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/phone_editText"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/phone_editText"
            android:layout_above="@+id/comments_list"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:onClick="foo"/>

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="430dp"
            android:id="@+id/comments_list"
            android:layout_below="@+id/phone_editText"/>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/item_list"
                    android:visibility="visible">
        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/comment_text"
                android:hint="enter comment"/>

        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add"
                android:id="@+id/add_btn"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/comment_text"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/comment_text"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="0px"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but yet i cannot place the `list` above the `bottom container`.

[image]

why cannot i use `wrap content` for the latter both height ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the list view has the wrong id of `comments_list`,  lets change it to `item_list` so that `bottom_container` will be placed below it.

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="430dp"
        android:id="@+id/item_list"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phone_editText"/>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/item_list"
                android:visibility="visible">
```